# How to access private member function using friend class object?

Tags: c++, friend

In `main`, I want to access the `display` function. Here, in `class B` I declared `class A` as friend. So i thought that it is possible to access the private member functions.
But i dont know how to do that.

```
#include<stdio.h>

class A
{ 
  public:
  class B
  {
    public:
     friend class A;
    private:
     void display()
     {
       printf("\nHi");
     }
  };
};

int main()
{
  //here i wanna access display function.. is it possible?
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You need an object (or two) first.

Comment: You need to add a `public` function in A that creates a `B` or accepts a reference or pointer to a `B` and calls `.display()` on it, then you can create an `A` in say `main()` and call the function you've added to `A`.  Anyway, if you're having this much trouble writing classes and objects, you shouldn't be worrying about how to nest them and declare friends... it's not going to help you do anything practical, and you should start with the easy stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [friend with class but can't access private members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271065/friend-with-class-but-cant-access-private-members)

Comment: Declaring `A` a friend means that you can access the private members from `A`, not from anywhere else. If you want to access it from anywhere, then make it public. (You could declare `main` to be a friend, but that would be weird).

Comment: Reconsider your design to avoid use of friend. Is it so bad if any function can access display? It doesn't seem to alter the state of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`friend` specifies what has access to private members. In your case, you want to access private members in the `main` function, so you should specify that it's friend:

```
class A
{ 
    public:
    class B
    {
       friend int main();
       void display()
       {
           printf("\nHi");
       }
    };
};

int main()
{
    // here you can access display function:
    A::B object;
    object.display();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make `class A` (and not anything else) a friend, then `class A` should access the `display` function. Any member of `class A` can do it:

```
class A
{ 
    public:
    class B
    {
       friend class A;
       void display()
       {
           printf("\nHi");
       }
    };

    // here you can access display function:
    void access_display(B object)
    {
        object.display();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A object1;
    A::B object2;
    object1.access_display(object2);
}
```